# jpackage additional launcher disable shortcut

Tags: java, jpackage

I have a simple application with the main launcher setup to run without console and an additional debug launcher to run with console (win-console=true).  I want the main launcher to have shortcut on the desktop and not the debug launcher, but there does not appear to have an option to disable the shortcut for the additional launcher.  I tried win-shortcut=false, icon=false.  Any idea if this is possible?

From the user's point of view, the additional launcher shortcut is confusing and unnecessary cluttering the desktop.